# Retrieving Single Database/Cell from table mysql to Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a program in which the label text will change according to the retrieved data. But the only thing/command I found are retrieving data by column or by record. I need to get only a single data/cell.

I already know how to connect and use sql commands in Vb.net by as I said earlier I can't retrieve a single data/cell.

I found a function called mysql_fetch_array but I think It's only for Php not for Vb or I am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will do it for you !**
*- you need the **limit** command added to your query !*
- for better performance i suggest using order by !

```
Dim conn as MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=db_name;")
    conn.Open()

    cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT col_name FROM table_name WHERE col_name='values' LIMIT 1", conn)
```